# adding registrations to an event

Tags: civievent, registration

Why can't I add additional registrations and payments for a given event to a contact whose email address has already been used for that event? If someone wishes to buy more tickets for the same performance, the system will not allow it and I can't do it in the back-end either. It just says that email contact is already assigned to the event.

Answer (score 1):

This is confusing in CiviCRM! If you check the same email address option on the Online Registration tab of the event configuration, it will allow multiple registrations per contact or email address.

Here are [details in the User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/online-event-registration/#setting-up-online-registration). The option is confusingly named and I have made a [change request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24649) to make it more clearly named (and have a little help text that you can pop up that explains it) in future versions of CiviCRM.

Comment: is it also possible that Nancy's 'matching rule' is on 'email only'?

Comment: I don't think the matching rule makes any difference here. If same email is allowed, it doesn't matter if it's the same contact or not because you can register one contact as many times as you like (and can register multiple contacts with the same email).

Comment: Could be. i was reading it that contact A had already registered (using the email) and now Contact B was also trying to register and was using the same email - and hence if matching rule is email only I would expect it to tell the anonymous user something along the lines that 'you are already registered' and hence prevent B being able to register.

Comment: Could be, but allowing same email fixes that problem too!

Comment: even if the registrations happen at different times? i (wrongly) assumed that only applied to a single occasion when multiple participants were being registered.

Comment: No, you're right. A different contact with the same email can register later even is same email isn't enabled. But the same contact can't register again later unless same email is enabled, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Thank you for this discussion. I am not an expert in this by any means, pretty much just took over from someone who left. I will look at the matching rule thing and see if that fixes my problem.